# Allow anonymous access to single mvc route

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to allow anonymous access to a single route:

```
public class GestionPantallaController : Controller
    {
        private GestionPantallaRepository repo = new GestionPantallaRepository();
        // GET: GestionPantalla
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var estado = repo.ObtenerEstado();
            return View(estado);
        }
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Estado()
        {
            var estado = repo.ObtenerEstado();
            return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(estado), "application/json");
        }
    }
```

the [AllowAnonymous] is not working, also I've tried adding in the web.config

```
  <location path="GestionPantalla/Estado">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

but I get the error "Location element is unused: no project item found at GestionPantalla\Estado"

I'm using Active Directory for authentication

Comment: the web.config one doesn't work I don't think because you don't physically have that path in your folder. When you say AllowAnonymous doesn't work, what error do you get exactly? Is your IIS setup configured to allow anonymous requests (as well as authenticated ones) for this application?

Comment: I'm making a request from a WPF application, locally, using IIS express for debugging. I receive a 401.2 error. So far I've used the workaround by using `UseDefaultCredentials = true` in the WPF  `HttpClient` but I'm not sure if this is going to work in the production environment. I might use credentials for this WPF application.

Comment: this is my current web.config https://pastebin.com/zmGcKy4c